# Parallel computation in R for saving data over loops

Tags: r, parallel.foreach, doparallel, snow

My efforts in applying parallel on the below simple code to save outputs with Openxlsx over multiple loops is failed.

Anyone can help please to convert this code to the parallel mode. This code on real size data (over 50 million observations, takes 13 hours to run). Reducing it even 2 hours is a big job for me.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


rawdata <- readxl::read_xlsx("~/Desktop/Book1.xlsx")


TYPE1 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "A") 
TYPE2 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "B") 

Split.TYPE1 <- split(TYPE1, TYPE1$Name) 
Split.TYPE2 <- split(TYPE2, TYPE2$Name) 


#--------------------------------- Save the TYPE A reports------------------------------------------------------------------------------
###################################(the foreach lines are coded)
for (nm in names(Split.TYPE1)){
#foreach(nm=1:names(Split.TYPE1), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  file<-paste0(nm,".xlsx")
  d1<-as.data.frame(Split.TYPE1[[nm]])

  wb<-createWorkbook(file)
  addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
  writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
}

# #------------------------------ Save the TYPE B in a folder ----------------------------------
for (dn in names(Split.TYPE2)){
   dnn <- paste0(dn)
  dir.create(dnn)
  sub_Split.TYPE2 <- split(Split.TYPE2[[dn]], Split.TYPE2[[dn]]$Surname)
  for (fn in names(sub_Split.TYPE2)){
    file<-file.path(dnn, paste0(fn,".xlsx"))

    d1<-as.data.frame(sub_Split.TYPE2[[fn]])
    wb<-createWorkbook(file)
    addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
    writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }}
```

Data:

```
Name    Surname TYPE
John    Greer   A
David   bear    A
Rose    beer    B
Tara    tea     B
Sam     Mac     B
Alan    Glass   B
Brad    Newman  A
Kristen Goodman A
Jessica Goodwin A
Heather Poker   B
```

Comment: Standard `for` loops don't run in paralllel in `R`. Try the `foreach` function in the `foreach` package.

Comment: Not sure how to apply Foreach for the second nested loop in my code. Nested Foreach codes usually come right after each one. Mine has something to do in the first layer of the nested loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I don't have your data, I made some small dummy sample.

The packages I used:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
```

This part from you and didn't change anything.

```
TYPE1 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "A") 
TYPE2 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "B") 

Split.TYPE1 <- split(TYPE1, TYPE1$Name) 
Split.TYPE2 <- split(TYPE2, TYPE2$Name)
```

Define the parallel backend. I'am using 6 cores here.

```
cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

This is your  first loop. Don't forget to add `.packages = "openxlsx"`. This makes sure the package gets also send to the worker. I change a little bit the code, because `nm in names(Split.TYPE1)` doesn't work for foreach. Maybe there is an easier solution, but I don't know it.

```
foreach(nm = 1:length(Split.TYPE1), .combine = cbind, .packages = "openxlsx") %dopar% {
  file <- paste0(names(Split.TYPE1)[nm], ".xlsx")
  d1 <- as.data.frame(Split.TYPE1[[names(Split.TYPE1)[nm]]])

  wb <- createWorkbook(file)
  addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = TRUE)
  writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

The second loop. I only used it once in the past and it worked quite well for me. This is how you can make a nested foreach loop. More info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf).

```
foreach(dn = 1:length(Split.TYPE2)) %:%
  foreach(fn = 1:length(unique(Split.TYPE2[[names(Split.TYPE2)[dn]]]$Surname)), .packages = "openxlsx") %dopar% {
    dnn <- paste0(names(Split.TYPE2)[dn])
    dir.create(dnn)
    sub_Split.TYPE2 <- split(Split.TYPE2[[names(Split.TYPE2)[dn]]], Split.TYPE2[[names(Split.TYPE2)[dn]]]$Surname)


    file <- file.path(dnn, paste0(names(sub_Split.TYPE2)[fn],".xlsx"))

    d1 <- as.data.frame(sub_Split.TYPE2[[fn]])
    wb <- createWorkbook(file)
    addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
    writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
```

And stop the parallel backend.

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

Using your data I get the following folder/file structure for the nested loop:

```
- Alan
    - Glass.xlsx
- Heather
    - Poker.xlsx
- Rose
    - beer.xlsx
- Sam
    - Mac.xlsx
- Tara
    - tea.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however, I have faced an error in the second loop running your sample as "Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0"" .  Also the second loop is not supposed to save all the sheets in each folder. As it coded in the original code it only saves split.Type2 files with same Surname in the related folder. So I think you misunderstood the way that second nested loop works. That's why I could not apply foreach yet. Appreciate it anyway.

Comment: You got the error when you ran my example? I just ran it on my computer, without any error. I'am using R 3.6.2, doParallel 1.0.15, foreach 1.4.7, openxlsx 4.1.4, tidyverse 1.3.0 on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS system.

Comment: I got exactly the same results with the normal for loop as the foreach loop. I'll have another go at it.

Comment: Correct me if I'am wrong. Is this correct in your nested loop: `(fn in names(Split.TYPE2))`, shouldn't this be `(fn in names(sub_Split.TYPE2))`? I made some adjustments to the nested foreach loop. It's not a nice solution. With nested foreach loops you need to have the iterators on before hand.

Comment: Thanks for your time. In the nested loop: first loop goes over split.TYPE2, and splits each of them based on the defined criteria to sub_split.TYPE2 and create a folder for each. Then the inner loop goes over the sup_split.TYPE2 and write the related outputs in the related folder. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, than I guessed correct. Did you try the updated code?

Comment: @ricdoerks, Thanks. yes, but still same. My problem is in the second loop as it is over a split set generated in the first layer: (please see the names() in each for here: 
for (dn in names(Split.TYPE2)){
   dnn <- paste0(dn)
  dir.create(dnn)
  sub_Split.TYPE2 <- split(Split.TYPE2[[dn]], Split.TYPE2[[dn]]$Surname)
  for (fn in names(sub_Split.TYPE2)){

Comment: So simply the code steps for the nested loop which is my problem is like this: 1) split rawdata 2) for over the split data TYPE2 3) split again the split.data TYPE2 4) for over the split split data(sum.split.TYPE2) 5) save data.

Comment: Can you show me your desired output using your example data, like I did in the updated answer? I updated the answer with the folder structure I get when I run the nested for loop and the nested foreach loop. They are identical.